# Add newline after email address

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, awk

All of the emails are saved in a text file, but without any spaces and many per line.
Looking for a way with Linux to sort them with a regex pattern for emails.

our_company_emails.txt:

```
    test1@sampleemail.comtest1@sampleemail.biztest1@sampleemail.infotest1@sampleemail.net
```

desired output:

```
    test1@sampleemail.com
    test1@sampleemail.biz
    test1@sampleemail.info
    test1@sampleemail.net
```

Comment: That wasn't really helpful.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Down voting doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: What happens if you have email addresses like `foo@bar.com`, `foo@bar.co`.

Comment: To see if there are any unprintable separators: `od -c our_company_emails.txt`

Comment: To add to @devnull's comment - is `bill@foo.comandy@bar.net` the email addresses for `bill@foo.com` and `andy@bar.net` or `bill@foo.co` and `mandy@bar.net`? How can you tell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if somehow your textfile is actually delimited with null character (0x00).

Basically you can do this:

```
grep -oE '[^@]+@[^@]+\.(com|net|biz|info)' our_company_emails.txt | sort
```

You could add more tlds to that.

If your text file is delimited with null characters, you can do this instead:

```
xargs -0 printf "%s\n" < our_company_emails.txt | sort
```

Comment: i like this one more...

Comment: Seems a lot simpler to do `tr \000 \\n` and just replace the nulls with newlines.  YMMV

Comment: This seems to work the best, except have to specify specifically all (sub) domains.. Thanks bro

Answer (score 2):

Simplest you could do is:

```
sed -r 's/([[:alnum:]]@[[:alnum:]]+\.)(com|info|biz|net)/\1\2\n/g' our_company_emails.txt
test1.asdf@sampleemail.com
test1.net@sampleemail.biz
test1@sampleemail.info
test1@sampleemail.net
bob@comcast.net
```

Add new domains, edit where necessary...

EDIT:

- corrected as advised by Ed Morton
- covers also cases where username contains dot(.) and domain suffix

Comment: At least lose the UUOC and anchor your RE so "bob@comcast.net" doesn't become "bob@com" on one line and "cast.net" on another.

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
sed -r 's/(.)(test1@)/\1\n\2/g' file
```

output:

```
test1@sampleemail.com
test1@sampleemail.biz
test1@sampleemail.info
test1@sampleemail.net
```

the group1 `(.)`, is just for skipping the substitution to happen on the first email address.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/test1/\n&/2g' file
```